# How to enable y-axis panning while zoom in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to move in Y-Axis while i am in zoom in charts 
Right now i am able to move on X-Axis while zooming

Bellow is the code for panning

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container1',
        type: 'column',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Possible solutions:

1. You could set vertical scrollbars in Highstock.

   ```
       yAxis: {
           scrollbar: {
               enabled: true
           }
       },
   ```

Article: http://www.highcharts.com/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/yaxis/scrollbar/

2. Use a wrapper code (included below) based on [the plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/27/Y-Axis%20Panning) suggested by **Barbara** that allows zooming (xy) and panning (xy).

The wrapper code:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'pan', function (proceed) {
        var chart = this,
            hoverPoints = chart.hoverPoints,
            doRedraw,
            e = arguments[1],
            each = H.each;

        // remove active points for shared tooltip
        if (hoverPoints) {
            each(hoverPoints, function (point) {
                point.setState();
            });
        }

        var mousePosX = e.chartX,
            mousePosY = e.chartY,
            xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
            startPosX = chart.mouseDownX,
            startPosY = chart.mouseDownY,
            halfPointRangeX = (xAxis.pointRange || 0) / 2,
            halfPointRangeY = (yAxis.pointRange || 0) / 2,
            extremesX = xAxis.getExtremes(),
            newMinX = xAxis.toValue(startPosX - mousePosX, true) + halfPointRangeX,
            newMaxX = xAxis.toValue(startPosX + chart.plotWidth - mousePosX, true) - halfPointRangeX,
            extremesY = yAxis.startingExtremes,
            newMaxY = yAxis.toValue(startPosY - mousePosY, true) + halfPointRangeY,
            newMinY = yAxis.toValue(startPosY + chart.plotHeight - mousePosY, true) - halfPointRangeY;

        if (xAxis.series.length && newMinX > Math.min(extremesX.dataMin, extremesX.min) && newMaxX < Math.max(extremesX.dataMax, extremesX.max) && newMinY > Math.min(extremesY.dataMin, extremesY.min) && newMaxY < Math.max(extremesY.dataMax, extremesY.max)) {
            xAxis.setExtremes(newMinX, newMaxX, false, false, {
                trigger: 'pan'
            });
            yAxis.setExtremes(newMinY, newMaxY, false, false, {
                trigger: 'pan'
            });
            doRedraw = true;
        }

        chart.mouseDownX = mousePosX;
        chart.mouseDownY = mousePosY;// set new reference for next run

        if (doRedraw) {
            chart.redraw(false);
        }
    });

}(Highcharts));
```

Starting extremes should be set in chart's callback or load event of a chart like:

```
    }, function(chart){
        chart.yAxis[0].startingExtremes = chart.yAxis[1].getExtremes();
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxjqed02/3/

Comment: @faisal Both demos are working - 1 - scroll using a scrollbar after zoom, 2 - hold shift and pan to scroll after zoom. If there is something not working please describe it and update a demo to show it.

Answer (score -1):

Y-Axis panning isn't built into HighCharts.  But, there is a plugin that does the trick:  http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/27/Y-Axis%20Panning
The examples show it working with highStock, but it works equally well with highCharts.

Comment: i have already tried out this plugin and it i think it works when zoom is 'false' i want to move in Y-Axis while i am in zoom

Comment: It seems quite intuitive to do y-axis panning, why highcharts don't have this feature built in? It's easier to turn on a switch like x-axis panning than to wrap the plugin.