# How to enable yaxis scrolling on highmaps in angular app

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using highmaps in an angular app.

I am able to zoom in, however, once I am zoomed in, I can move only on the x axis and not on the y axis.

I have tried using [yaxis-panning](https://github.com/RolandBanguiran/highstock-yaxis-panning) based on the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413390/how-to-enable-y-axis-panning-while-zoom-in-highcharts) question but it does not seem to work.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2paxj) is an online map where you can view the map, zoom in, scroll horizontally but not vertically after zoom.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on the online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel, added a stackblitz to the question, thank you.

Comment: I can't see your chart, some error occurs in the demo. Could you reproduce it once again?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work instantly but once you add an insignificant change (add empty line) and recompile, it shows the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reproducing it.

It is a regression which is already reported on Highcharts Github issue channel: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12671

Works fine in the 7.2.1 version. Ticket has higher priority so should be fixed soon. Until it will be done I encourage to use the previous version.